# How to Install Metasploitable on External Device

Tags: operating-system, virtual-machine, iso, metasploit

I want to Install metasploitable os on an external device like a computer or Raspberry Pi.

is it possible?

I download that but it have ".vmdk" format and it's not ".iso".
how can I convert it to iso or how can I have this OS on a computer?

Thanks.

Comment: Does my answer help at all?

Comment: no...Not yet :(

Answer (score 1):

There's a step or two but this should cover just about the whole process, it's been a while since I've tried it but I don't think much has changed since

```
sudo -i
wget http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/framework-latest.tar.bz2
apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install ruby subversion libpcap
tar jxpf framework-latest.tar.bz2
cd msf3
./msfconsole
```

However if you want more check out http://www.pwnpi.com/ which has a few extra tools included